# There are two lists of favorite sports. One's automated and one's user input. Find the intersection

Tags: python, for-loop, user-input, set-intersection

This assignment has a built-in IDLE so it has to work on that.
I Don't know the version update but am assuming it is 2.1-2.7
I tried the `set_a & set_b`  and the `set.intersect` thing but the software I use does not support that. 
I am going to attempt to incorporate if and for loops.
I have a rough idea to take each list element and compare it with the other until all have been compared so it any similarities are there just say how many and what the similarities are.

Here is the code:

```
#Khushi Desai
#7/20/18
#Purpose: To see if me and the user have any similarities
```

def main():

```
myFavSports = ["Gymnastics", "High Jumping", "Table Tenis", "Golf", "Ice Skating"]
length = len(myFavSports)

print(" My Favorite Sports")
print("--------------------")
for n in range(0, len(myFavSports)):
    print(str(n + 1) +". "+ myFavSports[n] + "!")


favSport1 = input("What is your first favorite sport?")
favSport2 = input("What is your second favorite sport?")
favSport3 = input("What is your third favorite sport?")
favSport4 = input("What is your fourth favorite sport?")
favSport5 = input("What is your fifth favorite sport?")

yourFavSports = [favSport1, favSport2, favSport3, favSport4, favSport5]


print("")
print(" Your Favorite Sports")
print("----------------------")
for n in range(0, len(yourFavSports)):
    print(str(n + 1) +". "+ yourFavSports[n] + "!")


in_both_lists = []
for myFavSports in myFavSports:
    for yourFavSports in yourFavSports:
        if myFavSports == yourFavSports:
            in_both_lists.append(myFavSports)

print "We both love {}: {}".format(
    len(in_both_lists),
    ", ".join(in_both_lists),
)
```

main()

Also, I tried this method but it is only comparing the first one.

Comment: In your `for`: You used the same variable name on both sides of the `in` - that is an issue.

Comment: BTW, a question title should generally describe *your* problem (that is, what's wrong with the code), not the problem your code is written to solve. Indeed, with a proper [mcve], the code included in the question is the smallest possible thing needed to illustrate the problem you're asking about, so other context (like the assignment you were trying to answer when you ran into the problem) should have been removed during the minimization process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution is using the same variable name for the item in the iteration and the name of the list. To fix your solution you can do this:

```
in_both_lists = []
for mySport in myFavSports:
    for yourSport in yourFavSports:
        if mySport == yourSport:
            in_both_lists.append(mySport)
```

Or you can simply do this:

```
in_both_lists = [sport for sport in yourFavSports if sport in myFavSports]
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a detailed piece of code. I don't get the second line of code though.

Comment: I used the code that you provided and it worked. Thank you so much. I didn't realize that the mistake was so minor. I  liked both of the explanations. You guys are the best!

Comment: The second method is a list comprehension. You can have some examples to understand better in this link https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Your `in_both_lists` loop is redefining `myFavSports` and `yourFavSports` as you are using the same variable name on each side of the loop.

Python loop syntax is defined as:

```
for item in list:
```

Currently you are using

```
for list in list:
```

so `list` gets redefined with the value of `item`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand this completely now. Thank you for the back syntax. I will try this out and get back to you.

Comment: I used the other answer code and it worked. This background understanding of my mistake helped me so much. I didn't realize it was so simple.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Sometimes it's more useful to understand the code you are writing rather than simply getting your code working.

Comment: Also, do you mind marking one of the two answers as correct? That way future users can easily tell which solution to use.